# Is the quotient ideal $JI^{-1}$ of two finitely generated fractional ideals $J,I$ finitely generated if both $I$ and $J$ contain a regular element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

Let $R$ be a noetherian ring without embedded primes (e.g. $R$ reduced). Let $I,J \subseteq \operatorname{Frac}(R)$ be two finitely generated $R$-submodules of $\operatorname{Frac}(R)$ both containing a regular element of $R$.

> Is $JI^{-1} = \{a \in \operatorname{Frac}(R) \mid aI \subseteq J\}$ finitely generated as an $R$-submodule of $\operatorname{Frac}(R)$?

The statement is clearly true if $J,I$ are invertible. But what about the general case?

**What I tried:**

Every $a \in JI^{-1}$ provides a map
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
  I & \stackrel{\cdot \ a}{\to} & J\\
  b & \mapsto & ab
\end{array}
$$
which should be an $R$-module homomorphism. This gives a map $\Phi:JI^{-1} \to \operatorname{Hom}_R(I,J)$ which turns out to be an $R$-module homomorphism. Moreover, if the multiplication with $a$ map $\phi_a: I \to J$ is the zero map, we have $ab = 0$ for all $b \in I$. By assumption, $I$ contains a regular element $b$ of $R$ and thus $ab = 0$ implies $a=0$. Finally, we obtain an $R$-module embedding $\Phi$ and now since $R$ is noetherian and both $I$ and $J$ are finitely generated, the same is true for the $R$-module $\operatorname{Hom}_R(I,J)$. In particular, $JI^{-1}$ is finitely generated as an $R$-module.

I guess the above should work, but I am not 100 percent sure. What do you think= If it does hold true, what about the non-noetherian case?

Comment: I don't know how you got that $JI^{-1}=J:I$. If $R=K[x,y]$ and $I=(x,y)$, then $I^{-1}=R$. If $J=I$ then $J\neq J:I$.

Comment: @user26857 Ah, okay, I see what you mean: for me $JI^{-1} = \{a \in \operatorname{Frac}(R) \mid aI \subseteq J\}$ was a definition, not an assertion. But you are right, I should call it $J:I$.